# How to create image inside a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div, an image(arrow.gif), another image(Untitled-1.jpg), two textboxes and a button.
I want to move the arrow.gif within a scrollable div with an image inside.

But i'm having a trouble creating the div into a scrollable one (making the Untitled-1.jpg fill the div) and moving the arrow.gif based on the Untitled-1.jpg's coordinates. Can anyone help me with this? Any help/assistance will be greatly appreciated .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Move to Click Position</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFF;
margin: 30px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
#contentContainer {
border: 5px black solid;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
cursor: pointer;
background-image:url('Untitled-1.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: fixed;

width:1030px;
height:912px
}
#thing {
position: relative;
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
height: 68px;
width: 41px;
transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
z-index: 10000;

}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="contentContainer">
<img id="thing" src="arrow.gif" >
</div>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="getClickPosition()">
<input type="text" id="valuex" name="valuex">
<input type="text" id="valuey" name="valuey">
</form>

<script src="prefixes.min.js"></script>
<script>



function getClickPosition() {
var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
var x1 = document.getElementById('valuex').value;
var y1 = document.getElementById('valuey').value;
var parentPosition = getPosition(x1.currentTarget);
var parentPosition = getPosition(y1.currentTarget);
var xPosition = x1 - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
var yPosition = y1- parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);

theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}

function getPosition(element) {
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 0;

while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}
return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as PHP ?

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: @ChrisMaggs i'm sorry, i haven't edited the code yet. The image(untitled-1.jpg) should came from the database.

Answer (score 0):

First things I'm noticing is that you have:

```
background-size: fixed;
```

*Fixed* isn't an option for the *background-size* property.

You also have:

```
height:912px
```

Which is missing a semicolon, and will break your stylesheet further on.

---

## 1) Full-size background

If you want your 'Untitled-1.jpg' image to fill the frame you could set *background-size* to either ***cover*** or ***contain***.

## 2) Scrollable div

In order to change your div into a scrollable one you can do so as follows:

```
#div{
     width:1030px;
     height:912px;
     overflow: auto;
     }
```

Overflow *auto* will add horizontal and vertical scrollbars to the div in the event that it extends outside its bounds. Or can use *scroll* if you want scrollbars to always be visible on the div.

You could also use *overflow-x* and *overflow-y* to specify which orientation you want scrollbars to appear.

## 3) Moving the thing

You're on the right track setting the position of the thing, there's a bit of fiddly stuff involved though to get it all functioning. See my Fiddle.

---

## Demo

I've modified your code a fair bit, but in this fiddle you can change the position of the thing within the scrollable div, using the coordinate boxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/8y0qhdwx/

---

I'm not sure where you are heading with this, but it would be worth looking into the HTML5 canvas element, as it's built to handle the positioning of objects within it.

Hope this helps.